# Sous Vide time for 1.5 lb 1 inch thick bone-in chuck roast at 140F

Tags: cooking-time, sous-vide

Would this require a 24+ hour bath at 140F, or would the limited thickness and size allow it be 12 hours?

Comment: What temperature are you planning on using?

Comment: I was looking at 140, but I am not bound to that temp

Comment: I assume that you are starting the meat straight from the fridge. That is quite a high temperature. At a glance (not checked quantitatively), I am going to suggest that the difference between 12 and 24 might not be that obvious both in terms of texture and diffusion of flavours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes very roughly 81 minutes for your meat to reach the 140F cooking temperature assuming you have just the meat and no marinade in the bag, and no part of the meat is frozen. The rest is all steady state cooking time. Based on my own experience, I am inclined to say that if there is any difference in texture and flavour between 12 hours and 24 hours, it is subtle to the extent that it may be noticeable in a side-by-side comparison.